# Why does my Victoria sandwich have a hole in the base?

Tags: baking, cake, sponge-cake

I've made the same cake recipe for years, no changes but suddenly my cakes look fine on top but when I turn them out there's a big hollow underneath! Help!

Comment: Are you sure there have been no changes? You're using the same tin lined the same way in the same oven?

Comment: A picture of the hole would help understand your problem

Comment: maybe its so tasty someone had to take a bite :)

Comment: Can you share your recipe and method? It might help to identify the potential problems.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing there was an accumulation of trapped air, either during the preparation of the batter/sponge cake mix, or when pouring into the pan/tin.